# Spinner не устанавливать значение пока не нажму(android)

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

У меня есть spinner:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int childposition, long id) {
        textView.setText(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        textView.setText("");
    }
    });
```

У меня есть `textView` При запуске программы, по стандарту туда устанавливается первое значение списка, т.е:

```
list.add("one");
list.add("two");
```

Когда я запущу свой пример то у меня в `textView` будет `one`.

**Вопрос:** как сделать так что б при запуске программы у меня был `textView.setText("")`  и только тогда когда я нажму на спиннер и выберу item то устанавливалось `textView.setText(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());` ?

Comment: Как вариант, можно добавлять первым элементом списка что-то вроде "Выберите ...", а к выбранному элементу обращаться по `getSelectedItemId()-1`. Но это скорее костыль, чем хорошее решение.

Comment: @РоманКотенко я пробовал делать типа того, к примеру добавляем в список элементы `list.add("one"); list.add("two"); list.add(""); Collections.reverse(list)` и пустой элемент становиться на первую позицию, но это тоже костыль

Comment: Могу вам показать как сделать выбор по умолчанию типа "Выберите..." но выбранное значение будет пустая строка.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

То что вы описали - нормальное поведение дефолтного Spinner. Это многим не нравится, поэтому появилось альтернативное решение https://github.com/justjohn/transitwidget/blob/master/src/com/transitwidget/NoDefaultSpinner.java. Добавьте этот класс в свой проект и используйте вместо стандартного Spinner - NoDefaultSpinner. У вас не будет выбираться первое значение по умолчанию, а в самом Spinner будет устанавливаться текст из атрибута prompt.

Comment: супер! То что доктор прописал)

Answer (score 4):

Есть более изящней способ вместо того что бы тянуть в проект левые исходники :-)

Все что нужно это назначить `OnItemSelectedListener` в методе `post()`
Выглядит это так:

```
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        textView.setText(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                        textView.setText("");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: интересно, спасибо)